# Find the point of function closest to a point not on the function

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the point on the graph of $y = x^2 $ that is closest to the point Q $(0,3)$. Let P be the point on the graph with coordinates $(x,x^2)$

I searched on Google and found [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-determine-the-shortest-distance-from-the-ordered-pair-1-4-to-the-graph-of-y-x-2) answer on Quora and here is what i did.

1. The distance between P and Q is given by $\sqrt{x^4 - 5x^2 + 9}$
2. The answer on Quora says that we need to find the derivative and that the roots of it will give us the answer.
3. $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 2x^3 - 5$ and the roots are $x_1 = 0, x_2 = +\sqrt{5}, x_3 = -\sqrt{5}$
4. I plug these into the distance equation and I get

$$ x = \pm2$$
$$x = \pm1 $$

My questions :

1. Is it normal that the graphs of these equations never crossed the points that I was looking for ? It probably is, but can you explain why ?
2. Why did we need the derivative to solve it ? I know that it gives us the slope at given point but how is that related to the problem ?
3. Why did we need the roots of the derivative ?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = 2x^3 - 5x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The graph above shows the parabola and the point $P(0,3)$. You are looking for the point(s) on the parabola closest to the point $P$. The square of the distance of the point $(x,x^2)$ on the parabola to $P$ is $f(x)=(x-0)^2+(x^2-3)^2=x^4-5x^2+9$. You want to minimize $f(x)$.

If we plot $f(x)$ we get:

[image]

You can see that there are two points where the distance is minimum. In both cases the gradient of the curve is flat at those points. So we want to find $x$ such that $f'(x)=0$.

Differentiating we get: $4x^3-10x=0$, so $x=0$ or $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}\approx\pm1.58114$.

Substituting into $f(x)$ we find that $f(x)=\frac{11}{4}$, so the minimum distance is $\frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}\approx1.65831$.

On your specific questions:

1. the minimizing points appear on the parabola. They also appear on the graph of $f(x)$.
2. Why the derivative? At a local minimum, the derivative is zero, as you can see from the second graph. Unfortunately, the derivative can also be zero at other points, such as $x=0$ in this case (which is a local maximum). So zero derivative is a necessary, but not a sufficient condition.
3. You need the roots of $f'(x)=0$ because you are looking for points with zero derivative.

Comment: The explanation was perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean for 1, is the graph $(x,x^2)$?

For 2. You want to minimize the distance which is equivalent to minimizing the square of the distance which is differentiable, therefore you can use the derivative to find the locl min/max (they will be critical points of the function)

3.You need the roots since the critical points are the ones that satisfy $f'=0$, so now you know all the local min/max and you need to figure out which one is the absolute min.